# Multi-region deployment of Google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

When deploying my app engine project I have set the location as us-central. As per [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations), this location refers to Iowa region. This is the region that will be used for my Datastore as well. However, as per [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#location-mr), this refers to the whole of United States with multi-regional availability. Where is my data in Datastore stored - is it regional or multi-regional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine and Datastore locations are indeed dependent. This comes from the fact that Datastore was originally accessible from App Engine only and designed in consequence.

You are asked to choose a location for your project app when you complete any of the following tasks:

- Create a new App Engine application.
- Create your first Cloud Datastore entity using the Google Cloud
  Platform Console.

When you choose a location for one of them, this location setting will also apply to the other. Now, as you noted, Datastore offers multi-region locations while App Engine doesn't. In your situation for example, **choosing us-central makes your App Engine application run in the Iowa region while your Datastore operates in a** [multi-zone and multi-region replicated configuration](https://cloud.google.com/docs/geography-and-regions#multi-regional_resources) within the US. By choosing another location where both App Engine and Datastore operate in a regional configuration like us-east1 for example, both will be located in South Carolina.